# iOS app eating nearly 40mb at start

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, memory-management

Hey, now when I finally got to test my app on a device it eats 40mb memory at the beginning which is a huge amount. Is there any good way to determine where exactly things went wrong?

Comment: You wrote it, dude, I'm sure you have a hunch about why it's doing that. Coming to us with a two-line question and no code is really not a likely shot at finding a solution.

Comment: I wondered if I was a prude for wanting to edit some of the language but then someone beat me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the memory allocations and leaks profilers that are part of the Instruments application.

Comment: I am running some checks now with them, commenting parts of the code off to determine the source.

Comment: I have tracked the memory consuption to UIWebView component which I have hidden to perform some operations, it eats like ~20mb.

Comment: Gonna open new question for the webView thing as it's pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to profile it using the Instruments app that comes with Xcode.